# when div reaches certain height in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a portfolio site [here](http://mrliger.com/).

I have the menu set to scroll when a menu item such as "contact" is clicked to that sections container. When this happens a little arrow on the left moves to show where in the site you are. My problem is when the user scrolls through the site without clicking the menu the arrow doesn't update its position as it is only programmed to move on click of the menu button. I have been thinking of a way to fix this and all I can think of is having the arrow update its position when one of the containers such as "contactcontainer" is at a certain point in the page (ideally when its 20px from the top of the page). Could anyone advise me of a javascript function that would calculate where abouts in the page a div is in relation to the top so I can write the jquery to make the arrow move?

Open to other suggestions if someone has a better way of making this work

Comment: params  = 'width='+screen.width;
                        params += ', height='+screen.height;
                        params += ', top=0, left=0';
                        params +=', scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes';

Answer (score 1):

#### ! UPDATED : to fix onclick menu active status

I made a simple scrollSpy demo here;

### DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/up4nu/4735/

No need to use bootstrap or another plugin. Hope your site can integrate with this.

#### JQUERY

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
            return item;
        }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top+1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function () {
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop) return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
        // Set/remove active class
        menuItems.parent().removeClass("active");
        menuItems.filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<ul id="top-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bar">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#baz">Baz</a></li>
    <li><a href="#car">Car</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div><a id="foo"></a>Foo</div>
    <div><a id="bar"></a>Bar</div>
    <div><a id="baz"></a>Baz</div>
    <div><a id="car"></a>Car</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    height:2200px;
}
#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:25%;
    background:yellow;
}
#top-menu li a{
    float: left;
    width:90%;
    border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background:yellow;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:5px 5% 7px 5%;
}
#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#top-menu li.active a {
    color: #000;
    background:url('http://iconshow.me/media/images/ui/ios7-icons/png/16/arrow-left-b.png') no-repeat right;
}
#content {
    float:right;
    width:75%;
}
#content div{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: ! UPDATED : to fix onclick menu active status.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.arrow-up-cover').offset();
```

Used your arrow as an example element.

Edit:

`.offset()` returns the elements position relative to the document. You can then hook a function to the scroll event and use something like `$(window).scrollTop()` to keep track of the top of the window as it moves. You just compare `.offset()` with `.scrollTop()` to know when to move the arrow.

Comment: so your saying i could use $('.contactcontainer').offset(); then set it a value like offset from top 20px to set of a function that moves the arrow?

Comment: ok, so would it look something like: if $(window).scrollTop() > $('.portfoliocontainer').offset(); then move arrow?

Comment: `offset` only works for the first element of the list, so you should use ids. `if($('.portfoliocontainer').offset().top<$(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop())` will return true as soon as the element comes up from the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in js function

```
params  = 'width='+screen.width;
params += ', height='+screen.height;
params += ', top=0, left=0';
params +=', scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are you willing to, but, you can use the bootstrap "Scroll Spy" utility. If you wanna know more, here you go!:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: is there a similar jquery plugin without having to use bootstrap by any chance? Scrollspy looks perfect but i've never used bootstrap before...

Comment: I dont know if there is a plugin for Jquery :(, im sorry i cannot help you!